# Google maps error occurs in searchbar when clicked on particular address

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am displaying address in search bar but for some places when i click the cell error occurs.I have attached code below.

> error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
>   reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond
>   bounds [0 .. 0]'

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            let urlpath = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(self.searchResults[indexPath.row])&sensor=false".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
            let url = URL(string: urlpath!)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                do {
                    if data != nil{
                        let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                        let status = dic.value(forKey: "status") as! String
                        print("\(status)")
                        if status == "OK"
                        {
                        let lat =   (((((dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "geometry") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "lat")) as? Double
                        let lon =   (((((dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "geometry") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "lng")) as? Double
                        if let latitude = lat
                        {
                            if let longitude = lon
                            {
                                self.delegate.locateWithLongitude(longitude, andLatitude: latitude, andTitle: self.searchResults[indexPath.row])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Add if ((dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).count > 0 Condition after your status got OK, and write your code in this if condition

Comment: not working @SapanaRanipa error occurs

Comment: you getting error, because your array is empty or array.count < indexPath.row and you trying to fetch object of that index which actually not contain any object at that index, please check this condition and try, if ((dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).count > indexPath.row

Comment: I just post same answer

Comment: if my answer is work for you then please accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let urlpath = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(self.searchResults[indexPath.row])&sensor=false".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        let url = URL(string: urlpath!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            do {
                if data != nil{
                    let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                    let status = dic.value(forKey: "status") as! String
                    print("\(status)")
                    if status == "OK"
                    {
                    let lat =   (((((dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "geometry") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "lat")) as? Double
                    let lon =   (((((dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "geometry") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "lng")) as? Double
                    if let latitude = lat
                    {
                        if let longitude = lon
                        {
                            self.delegate.locateWithLongitude(longitude, andLatitude: latitude, andTitle: self.searchResults[indexPath.row])
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
}
```